# intstream fails to parse array of type string to type int

Tags: java, arrays, string, parseint

i do not know why this string fail to parse. i try to parse  an array of string to an array of int.any help is appreciated.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input =sc.nextInt();

        String[] b = Integer.toBinaryString(input).split("[0]+");


        int [] intArray = new int[b.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
             //this where the error seems to be 
            intArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(b[i]);

            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
            }

        int highestConsecutiveOnes = intArray[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            if (intArray[i]> highestConsecutiveOnes){
                highestConsecutiveOnes= intArray[i];
            }
        }
        int [] highestConsecutiveOnesArray = Integer.toString(highestConsecutiveOnes).chars().map(c -> c -= '0').toArray();
        int sumOfMostConsecutiveOnes = Arrays.stream(highestConsecutiveOnesArray).sum();
        System.out.println(sumOfMostConsecutiveOnes);

        }
```

it returns NumberFormatException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111111111111111"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at testrun.Tester.main(Tester.java:19)
```

Comment: That's too big. Try `Long.parseLong`.

Comment: Store just the length `n` for `n` ones: `sum(i=0; i < n) 10^i`. Or store `Integer.parseInt(b[i], 2);` or `Long.parseLong(b[i], 2)` if you know that no more than 31 resp. 63 consecutive 1s are present;

Comment: thanks. can you please explain the first part of your answer more.